# Does MyBatis support like operator?

Tags: sql, mybatis

Do you know how to write like sql in MyBatis? I Googled a lot without any feasible solution. It always returns bad SQL error. I need to pass Chinese character after like.

Comment: Are you sure it's the 'like' and not the Chinese character? Does a like query with ASCII text return an SQL error? This could be a UTF conversion issue.

Comment: I really dont think Chinese character will cause any issue. Now, it has been solved by concat '%' to the input string. Anyway, thanks a lot.